# Passing a list of class from viewmodel (view to controller) using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller, asp.net-ajax

i have a view which contains viewmodel as model. i want to send one of the class from viewmodel (which is list of some class) from view to controller to a action.

this is my view model

```
public class CustomClass
    {
        public ABC objABC { get; set; }
        public DEF objDEF { get; set; }
        public List<XYZ> objXYZLst { get; set; }
    }
```

this is XYZ class

```
 public class XYZ
    {
        public long RelationPersonId { get; set; }
        public string Relationship { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNo { get; set; }
        public string PropertyName { get; set; }
        public bool IsPropertyError { get; set; }

    }
```

this is my view call

```
  var url = "@Url.Action("ActionName", "ContollerName")";
  var model = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.objXYZLst))';
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: url,
        data: JSON.stringify(model),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            $("#dvLst").html(data);
        }
    });
```

and this is my action

```
[HttpPost]
        public PartialViewResult ActionName(List<XYZ> model)
        {
            return PartialView(model);
        }
```

value is always null in controller and Model.objXYZLst is having two data arrays.
please help

Comment: could you please post your code for view.

Comment: What is the point of passing exactly the same unchanged collection from the view to the controller that the controller just sent to the view (just get it again as you did in the GET method. But since you already have it, just render the collection in the view inside a loop or just use `@Html.Partial("ActionName", Model.objXYZLst)`

Comment: @ haim770- thanx bro..got 2 count

Comment: @ Stephen Muecke- actually i am doing something else i wrote here only for problem i was facing.

Answer (score 2):

You have declared a string variable here:

```
var model = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.objXYZLst))';
```

whereas you need a javascript object, so get rid of the surrounding quotes and it will work:

```
var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.objXYZLst));
```

Another problem with your code is the expected return type that you specified:

```
dataType: "json",
```

but your controller action returns HTML fragments:

```
public PartialViewResult ActionName(List<XYZ> model)
{
    return PartialView(model);
}
```

When jQuery attempts to deserialize this HTML back to a javascript object it will fail and your `success` callback will not be invoked on the client. So get rid of this `dataType: "json",` as well and leave jQuery use the Content-Type response header to infer it automatically.

Comment: but yes after returning from action it was not rendering the content in div as data type was json, i removed that and now working. thanx  for the info